# VS 2010 Upper case highlighted text using keyboard short cut?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a highlighted string, I would like to toggle the case of for example Upper / Lower. Is this possible using a keyboard shortcut in vs 2010?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With default settings, should be

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for upper case, and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for lower case.

Comment: It's also worth noting that those menu items are located under Edit > Advanced.